# SDL Tridion GUI extension add deck page from extension configuration file

Tags: tridion

I've figured out how to inject a DeckPage into the GUI using javascript.  I was wondering if there is a neater way to do this using the extension configuration.   For example here is how a tab can be added to the page view in the CME:

```
<ext:tabpages>
          <ext:add>
          <ext:extension name="Name of Tab" assignid="TabName" insertbefore="">
            <ext:control>~/tab.ascx</ext:control>
            <ext:pagetype/>
            <ext:apply>
              <ext:view name="PageView">
                <ext:control id="MasterTabControl"/>
              </ext:view>
            </ext:apply>
          </ext:extension>
          </ext:add>
</ext:tabpages>
```

And I see it's possible to create a `<ext:PageDeck>` item within the configuration, but so far I've not managed to get the file tab.ascx to display within one.

I'm trying to display the ascx in the Page View, within the Component Presentations tab (select a component presentation) and two PageDecks are shown 'Component Presentation' and 'Target Groups'

Here is what my attempted XML configuration looks like:

```
<ext:deckpages>
  <ext:add>
    <ext:extension name="Target Groups Editor" assignid="TargetGroupEditor" insertbefore="">
      <ext:control>~/tab.ascx</ext:control>
      <ext:pagetype></ext:pagetype>
      <ext:apply>
        <ext:view name="PageView">
          <ext:container name="ComponentPresentationsTab">
            <ext:container name="ComponentPresentationPropertiesTabControl">
              <ext:control id="targetGroups"/>
            </ext:container>
          </ext:container>
        </ext:view>
      </ext:apply>
    </ext:extension>            
  </ext:add>
</ext:deckpages>
```

I've opened up the CME code files (Page.aspx, ComponentPresentations.ascx) to obtain most of these ids and drill down through them, but i'm making a lot of assumtions as to what the `<ext:container>` is for and what can be associated to the `<ext:control>`.

If anyone has done something like this and knows if it's possible i'd be really happy to know the answer... I'd prefer to use the XML, rather than injecting via javascript.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that would still be a tab. Try:

```
  <ext:tabpages>
    <ext:add>
      <ext:extension insertbefore="targetGroups" assignid="TargetGroupEditor" name="Target Groups Editor">
      <ext:control>~/tab.ascx</ext:control>
      <ext:pagetype>TargetGroupEditor</ext:pagetype>
      <ext:apply>
        <ext:view name="PageView">
          <ext:control id="ComponentPresentationPropertiesTabControl" />
        </ext:view>
      </ext:apply>
    </ext:extension>
    </ext:add>
  </ext:tabpages>
```

Comment: Thanks alvin, you are absolutely right.  I was going down the wrong path with the <ext:deckpages>, even though I want to add to the deckpages, this must still be configured using a <ext:tabpages> :)

Answer (score 0):

I've added some deck pages before.

None of those used ext:container elements, but otherwise the XML looked like yours.

Have you tried it without those and just the "targetGroups" control?

Comment: thanks peter.  would be interested to see your example using <ext:deckpages> in terms of just getting stuff into the CME